# Postgresql averaging neighbouring data into new table with sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

Here is the data structure. `date` is unique but could be missing (means jumping dates but not NULL) and is out of order. If the number of records is odd, just omit the last record.

```
date       | value | value2
-----------+-------+--------
2017-10-11 |    10 |    0.2
2017-10-13 |    22 |    0.3
2017-10-12 |     6 |    0.0
2017-10-14 |    20 |    0.6
         ...
```

I want to have the nearest two records to merge with the new value using the **average** of the value of record-to-merge. Using **SQL** **only**.

Expecting result.

```
date       | value | value2
-----------+-------+--------
2017-10-11 |     8 |    0.1
2017-10-13 |    21 |   0.45
         ...

2017-10-11 merged 2017-10-11 and 2017-10-12, i.e. value = AVG(10,6) = 8
2017-10-13 merged 2017-10-13 and 2017-10-14, i.e. value = AVG(22,20) = 21
```

Comment: what's the logic here? what have you tried? what if you have missing dates?

Comment: @VamsiPrabhala I'm not sure if postgresql is capable of doing this kind of merging and averaging without the help of other language.

Comment: @VamsiPrabhala There could be missing dates and out of order, but they will be unique.

Comment: If no date "2017-10-12" in table, then "2017-10-11" must be merged with "2017-10-13" ? What to do if number of record odd  ?

Comment: @Mike Yes. In this case, if there is no 2017-10-12, 2017-10-11 must merge with 2017-10-13. If odd records, just omit the last record.

Comment: `lag()` and `lead()` come to mind about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select min(date), avg(value), avg(value2)
  from (
    select *, (row_number() over(order by date)-1)/2 grp
      from Table1
  ) X
group by grp
```

Demo on [sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/e92e3/6)

Comment: This is awesome